# Can I use gdal_translate to resample a comma separated x,y,z file to lower density?

Tags: gdal

Anyone know how (if) I can use gdal at the command prompt level to subsample an ascii comma separated dems file to lower density data?  I've been trying to use gdal_translate -outsize but haven't had any success.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
gdal_translate.exe -outsize 400 200 src.dem trg.dem
```

start from GDAL>=2.0, support resampling algorithm selection by using:

```
-r {nearest (default),bilinear,cubic,cubicspline,lanczos,average,mode}
```

more information in http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html